# Fortran - Maxval returns weird results when dimension is specified

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have a 3x2 array and have filled it with the numbers 1-6
so that it looks like
1 4
2 5
3 6

I then call maxval on it, and specify that I wish to find the max value along dimension 1. One would expect that it should return 3, no?

But for some reason my output is '3    6'

```
PROGRAM maxv
    IMPLICIT None
    INTEGER, DIMENSION(3,2) :: x
    DATA x /1,2,3,4,5,6/

    WRITE(*,*) maxval(x,dim=1)
ENDPROGRAM maxv
```

I used Gfortran 4.6.3 if the issue lies within my compiler

According to http://www.nsc.liu.se/~boein/f77to90/a5.html , maxval when you specify a dimension is supposed to supply the maxval in that dimension.

Or maybe I have overlooked some stuffs.

Comment: @Serenity is there any reason why Fortran questions should not use the GCC tag while C or C++ yes?

Comment: Where gcc here? It is fortran.

Comment: @Serenity While I agree that the gfortran tag is somewhat better, please note that the GCC tag reads *"GCC is the GNU Compiler Collection. It's the de facto standard C compiler on Linux and supports many other languages and platforms as well."* GCC does not mean GNU C Compiler, it means GNU Compiler Collection. This includes Fortran.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you *overlooked some stuffs*;  `maxval` is behaving correctly.

When you write, for a rank-2 array `x`

```
maxval(x,dim=1)
```

the function returns a rank-1 array with the same number of elements as there are columns in `x`, each element being the maximum value of the corresponding column in `x`.  Similarly

```
maxval(x,dim=2)
```

would, for your example, return the rank-1 array `[4,5,6]` -- the maximum value in each row of `x`.

[The GNU documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/MAXVAL.html) explains the function better than the source you cite, [IBM](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlf101l.doc/xlflr/maxval.htm) explain it even better and include an example of the function's use.

Comment: So how would one get the max value residing in a certain dimension? Select a slice before calling maxval?

Comment: What do you mean by *the max value residing in a certain dimension* ?

Comment: Oh, right. I meant max value in one band/slice/vector. I think I get it now. Thanks.